# Timer in Windows 8 app in background

Tags: windows-8

I'm toying with Windows 8 SDK and I'd like to create an app that does something when a timer elapses. I've found out that when the  app is suspended, the DispatcherTimer stops and resumes when the app comes back into the foreground. However, I'd like to schedule timer updates also in the background. What is the preferred solution to this problem (scheduling task for the future while the app is in background)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Background task. Take a look to the example available at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Task-Sample-9209ade9.

Answer (score 0):

I found following article really helpful when working with `BackgroundTask`

[31 Days of Windows 8 | Day #12: Background Tasks](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2012/11/12/31-days-of-windows-8-day-12-background-tasks/)